# TestCafe: Using the same Selector across multiple tests is returning old, incorrect data

Tags: testing, css-selectors, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have several similar pages that all load up several header elements based on various inputs. They are auto-generated.

I am writing a test cafe test to confirm that the correct headers have loaded in the correct order for each page. Some pages have more headers, some pages have fewer headers.

My tests all follow the same basic pattern:

```
test.disablePageCaching('log in and check that columns load in correct order',
    async(tc: TestController)=>{
        const myPage = new MyPage(tc)
        await tc.expect(myPage.getScreen().exists).ok() // Confirm page load
        myPage.nagivateToRelevantPage();
        const headers = Selector(headerClassName)
        const expectedHeaders = ['array','of','expected','values']
        const count = await headers.count
        for (let i =0; i<count;i++){
            const text = await headers.nth(i).innerText.toLowerCase()
            await tc.expect(expectedHeaders[i].toLowerCase()).eql(text)
        }
```

(if you spot any small syntax errors, please rest assured that it isn't a matter of an errant parenthesis or a misspelled variable name)

I have 4 of these tests in the same file, and I hop from one to the next. The thing is, I seem to be retaining old data when I hop from one text to the next.

Say my first test checked 10 header elements; my headers.count value is 10. If my second test only contains 3 header elements, I would expect my headers.count value to be 3. Instead, my headers.count value is still 10. Test Cafe seems to just be overwriting the previous data, while retaining the data from the previous test.

Is there an option of some sort to tell Test Cafe to purge this old data in between tests? I have tried the disablePageCaching option, but that is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually figured this out; the issue was that I was collecting data too soon after navigating to a new page. I needed to call `await tc.expect(myPage.getScreen().exists).ok()` after navigating to the new page; that gave test cafe enough time to recognize which data was new and which data was old.